# INNER JOIN COM WHERE MYSQL

Tags: php, join, inner

Eu tenho um foreach que roda cada produto, depois gostaria de fazer uma consulta em duas tabelas a partir desse ID, só que não estou conseguindo, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $key => $produto) {
$id = $produto->getId();

$produto_loaded = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

$id_prd = $produto_loaded->getId();  

$teste = $id_prd;
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste2');
$link->set_charset("utf8");
$query =
"SELECT catalog_product_website.website_id as websiteid, catalog_category_product.category_id as categoria, catalog_category_product.position as positioncat
FROM catalog_product_website
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product
ON catalog_product_website.websiteid = catalog_category_product.product_id
WHERE n.websiteid = '$teste'";
$select = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
$test = array(
$row['websiteid'],
$row['categoria'],
$row['positioncat']);
print_r($test);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.website_id as websiteid, 
b.category_id as categoria, 
b.position as positioncat
FROM catalog_product_website a
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product b
ON a.website_id = b.product_id
WHERE a.websiteid = '$teste'";
```

Teste esse script

Comment: Estou printando os valores mas não recebo nada :\

Comment: alterei o script, tenta novamente...

Comment: Erro meu, eu estava comparando o website_id com product_id, era esse meu erro, seu código está certo, obrigado.

Comment: Marca como respondido por favor!

Comment: Faltam 3 minutos para poder marcar.

Comment: Ok, Valeu! Esquece nao... é importante para mim!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69168/discussion-between-danillo-victtor-and-gustavo-souza).